# What Version Of Polymer Did He Use?

Tags: html, polymer

I was watching a pretty neat [YouTube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bm_lCImE_9M) about Polymer, but it's about a year old, and all the file names in polymer have changed. I've tried to import polymer.html and webcomponents.js (instead of paper-elements.html and platform.js), and it's still not working like in the video. I'm trying to figure out what version he used in the video.
Thanks!

Comment: The latest possible version he could have been using, judging by the upload date of that video, is Stable Release 0.4.2. The next version, 0.5.0, didn't come out until a month later.

Answer (score 0):

As Tyler said, probably 0.4.2. O.4.2 is so old that too many things have changed to make it a decent tutorial these days.

I would learn from 1.0, using the material on the polymer site. (You could use use bower to use 0.4.2 for the YouTube tutorial, but I would highly recommend using 1.0 material instead)